# Восстановление админки в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день, друзья! У меня такой вопрос, кто работал с битриксом? У меня заказчик дал один сайт, а руководство поставило задачу решить поставленную задачу в кратчайшие сроки (за сегодня). Проблема в следующем, в админки отсутствуют списки, поля, заголовки и прочее, нету также нотисов, сообщений от битрикса. Как решить эту ситуацию. Прилагаю скрины.

[image]
[image]

Как видно из картинок, управление сайта полуфункциональное, пытался редактировать компоненты. В моем случае это catalog.section но там разобраться сложно без разметки. Как решить эту проблему? Обновление не предлагать.

Comment: Тут много причин может быть, может неправильно прописан компонент, может изменен криво, а может глюк. С разбегу не решить

Comment: это не только в компоненте одном, это везде так. В административной части тоже нотисы отсутствуют.

Comment: Тогда вам прямая дорога в техподдержку.

Answer (score 2):

1)утеряли наверное файл .parameters.php в компоненте.
2)http://take.ms/sqKjJ

Comment: спасибо за ответы. Буду разбираться!

Answer (score 2):

Одна из возможных причин - неправильные права доступа к файлам/папкам.

Их можно установить через командную строку из папки сайта, например, так (для файлов и папок раздельно, вернет количество установленных файлов/папок):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; -exec echo {} \; | wc -l
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; -exec echo {} \; | wc -l
```

Также может быть неправильный владелец файлов, установка владельца рекурсивно:

```
find . -exec chown username:groupname {} \; -exec echo {} \; | wc -l
```

Comment: уважаемый, папки/файлы и инфоблоки никак не связаны между собой. Так что ваш совет неверен. Сами поняли что написали?

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под инфоблоками? Я вижу, что в данный момент у вас проблема с языковыми файлами, они в инфоблоках не хранятся, и в базе данных тоже, это уж точно :) Связь между папками/файлами и инфоблоками такова, что модуль инфоблоков написан на php, и представляет из себя набор файлов. Права доступа к файлам - это первое что я бы стал проверять в вашем случае, потом - наличие этих файлов вообще.